# Sed - Copy function arguments and comments

Tags: sed

C file has 100s of lines with strlcpy, I have to copy the first parameter and add as the a third argument for the strlpcy using - Eg `p->account  to sizeof(p->account)`

**Input**

```
strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast));      //Set Account Information
strlcpy(p->balance,gettoken(NULL,&plast));
strlcpy(p->startDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0')); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->endDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0')); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->status,gettoken(NULL,&plast));
```

**Expected Output**  (Copy the first parameter and add as a third argument - pass as parameter for sizeof ());

```
strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->account));     //Set Account Information
strlcpy(p->balance,gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->balance));
strlcpy(p->startDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0'),sizeof(p->startDate)); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->endDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0'),sizeof(p->endDate)); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->status,gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->status));
```

Current Ouput (Incorrect Result)

```
sed 's/^\([^\s]*strlcpy[^(]*\)\(([^,]*\),\([^)]*[^)][^;]\).*/\1\2,\3,sizeof\2));/' kkk1.txt

strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->account));
strlcpy(p->balance,gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->balance));
strlcpy(p->startDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->startDate));
strlcpy(p->endDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->endDate));
strlcpy(p->status,gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->status));
```

Line1, 3, and 4 Failed to Print the comments at the end of line

Line 3 and 4 : `skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0')` - Parameter '0' failed to get copied in the result along with skipchr() in the result.

Guide me with the correct sed command. Thanks in Advnace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In general**, such a task is beyond the power of sed.  That's because C has an (approximately) *context-free* grammar, which cannot be parsed using only *regular* expressions.  Regular grammars cannot describe arbitrarily nested parentheses, for example.

**However**, if you have sufficient constraints on your inputs, you can use sed for your specific, constrained, source code.  In this case, it appears that we can make these assumptions:

- Each relevant statement is on a single line
- There is only one statement on each relevant line.
- The first argument contains no commas.
- There are no string literals or comments that might accidentally match.

Given these constraints, we want to match:

1. The `strlcpy` name and opening parenthesis (with optional space between): `\bstrlcpy\s*(`
2. The first argument, up to the first comma: `[^,]+`
3. The rest of the arguments: `,.+`
4. The final closing parenthesis and semicolon: `)\s*;`

We then want to substitute this with the same text, except that we want `sizeof` group 2 interposed between groups 3 and 4 in the replacement: `\1\2\3, sizeof \2\4`.

Putting this together into a GNU sed one-liner:

```sed
#!/bin/sed -rf

s/\b(strlcpy\s*\()([^,]+)(,.+)(\)\s*;)/\1\2\3, sizeof \2\4/
```

Feeding your sample code through this gives the desired output:

```c
strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast), sizeof p->account);      //Set Account Information
strlcpy(p->balance,gettoken(NULL,&plast), sizeof p->balance);
strlcpy(p->startDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0'), sizeof p->startDate); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->endDate,skipchr(gettoken(NULL,&plast),'0'), sizeof p->endDate); /* YYYYMMDD */
strlcpy(p->status,gettoken(NULL,&plast), sizeof p->status);
```

(Note: I didn't include the unnecessary parentheses around the argument to `sizeof`, as that makes it look like applying `sizeof` to a type rather than to an expression; if you feel very strongly that you want them, it's not difficult to do.  But I don't encourage it.)

Comment: Thanks for the  solution and lucid explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ str="strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast));"
$ sed -re '/strlcpy/{s/(\([^,]*)([^\)]*\))/\1\2,sizeof\1\)/}' <<< "$str"
strlcpy(p->account,gettoken(NULL,&plast),sizeof(p->account));
```

Here's the brief explanation,

- `/strlcpy/`: find the line matched "strcpy", and use behind script to process it
- `(...)`: `\1` and `\2`  refer to the corresponding matching regex between parentheses `(...)`. Mind that because of the `-r` parameter, no need to escape the parentheses.
- The regex pattern which contains parentheses, they need to be escaped as `\(`
- The final step to edit the files in place, add `-i` option to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
sed 's/^\(\s*strlcpy(\)\([^,]\+\)\(,.*\)\();.*\)$/\1\2\3,sizeof(\2)\4/'
```